Why do values ($v_{\pi}(s)$) decrease in Sutton Barto's Reinforcement Learning Figure 4.1 example?
I'm confused how the iterations go with decreasing $v_{\pi}(s)$ in Figure 4.1 example in the book.
Figure 4.1 example in the book
When it was random, the values were 0 but with iterations, the values decrease to -14, -22.
As can be seen, when k increases, the values seem to all decrease but I thought that we want $v_{\pi'}(s) ≥ v_{\pi}(s)$ for all $s$, as given in equation 4.8 with iterations, where $\pi'$ is the new policy and $\pi$ is the old policy.
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Its fairly easy to see this for the random policy for which all actions $\{\uparrow,\downarrow,\leftarrow,\rightarrow \}$ have equal probability. You start with a grid for which $v_0=0$ for all grid points:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
0 & 0_1 & 0_2 & 0_3 \\
\hline
0_4 & 0_5 & 0_6 & 0_7 \\
\hline
0_8 & 0_9 & 0_{10} & 0_{11} \\
\hline
0_{12} & 0_{ 13} & 0_{14} & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Any action for all grid points (except from the terminal points at the upper left and lower right corner which always have a value of 0) results in a reward equal to -1. Falling off the grid also results in a -1 reward but there is no change of state.
For the first iteration the random policy generates a transition to a grid point of zero value. For each of these transitions the reward is -1. So, for example,
$$
\begin{matrix}
& & \fbox{$0_1$} &  \\
 &  & \uparrow_{-1} &  &  \\
\fbox{$0_4$} & \stackrel{-1}{\leftarrow} & \fbox{$0_5$} & \stackrel{-1}{\rightarrow} & \fbox{$0_6$} \\ 
&  & \downarrow_{-1}  &  &  \\
& & \fbox{$0_9$} &
\end{matrix}
$$
gives a value of -1 for grid point 5. Note that the same is the case for grid point 4 since
$$
\begin{matrix}
& & \fbox{$0$} &  \\
 &  & \uparrow_{-1} &  &  \\
\fbox{$0_4$} & \stackrel{-1}{\leftarrow} & \fbox{$0_4$} & \stackrel{-1}{\rightarrow} & \fbox{$0_5$} \\ 
&  & \downarrow_{-1}  &  &  \\
& & \fbox{$0_8$} &
\end{matrix}
$$
Repeating this for all grid points we get
$$
\def\a{-1}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
0 & \a_1 & \a_2 & \a_3 \\
\hline
\a_4 & \a_5 & \a_6 & \a_7 \\
\hline
\a_8 & \a_9 & \a_{10} & \a_{11} \\
\hline
\a_{12} & \a_{ 13} & \a_{14} & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
In step $k=2$ we get some differentiation for policy values; for grid point 5 we have
$$
\begin{matrix}
& & \fbox{${-1}_1$} &  \\
 &  & \uparrow_{-1} &  &  \\
\fbox{${-1}_4$} & \stackrel{-1}{\leftarrow} & \fbox{${-1}_5$} & \stackrel{-1}{\rightarrow} & \fbox{${-1}_6$} \\ 
&  & \downarrow_{-1}  &  &  \\
& & \fbox{${-1}_9$} &
\end{matrix}
$$
which gives a value of -2. For grid point 4 we have
$$
\begin{matrix}
& & \fbox{$0$} &  \\
 &  & \uparrow_{-1} &  &  \\
\fbox{${-1}_4$} & \stackrel{-1}{\leftarrow} & \fbox{${-1}_4$} & \stackrel{-1}{\rightarrow} & \fbox{${-1}_5$} \\ 
&  & \downarrow_{-1}  &  &  \\
& & \fbox{${-1}_8$} &
\end{matrix}
$$
giving a value of $-7/4$ or $-1.7$ to 1 d.p. Repeating this for all grid points we get
$$
\def\a{-2}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
0 & {-1.7}_1 & \a_2 & \a_3 \\
\hline
{-1.7}_4 & \a_5 & \a_6 & \a_7 \\
\hline
\a_8 & \a_9 & \a_{10} & {-1.7}_{11} \\
\hline
\a_{12} & \a_{ 13} & {-1.7}_{14} & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
As you can see getting the values for the rest of the iteration is fairly trivial. As the values in the edges change we get more differentiation. For $k=3$ the value for grid point 5 is given by
$$
\begin{matrix}
& & \fbox{${-1.7}_1$} &  \\
 &  & \uparrow_{-1} &  &  \\
\fbox{${-1.7}_4$} & \stackrel{-1}{\leftarrow} & \fbox{${-2}_5$} & \stackrel{-1}{\rightarrow} & \fbox{${-2}_6$} \\ 
&  & \downarrow_{-1}  &  &  \\
& & \fbox{${-2}_9$} &
\end{matrix}
$$
This is equal to
$$
\frac{2}{4}\left(-\frac{7}{4} -1\right)+\frac{2}{4} (-2-1)=-\frac{46}{16}
$$
which is equal to -2.9 to 1 d.p. (-2.875 is the exact value). For grid point 6 we have
$$
\begin{matrix}
& & \fbox{${-2}_2$} &  \\
 &  & \uparrow_{-1} &  &  \\
\fbox{${-2}_5$} & \stackrel{-1}{\leftarrow} & \fbox{${-2}_6$} & \stackrel{-1}{\rightarrow} & \fbox{${-2}_7$} \\ 
&  & \downarrow_{-1}  &  &  \\
& & \fbox{${-2}_{10}$} &
\end{matrix}
$$
which gives a value of -3. For grid point 7
$$
\begin{matrix}
& & \fbox{${-2}_3$} &  \\
 &  & \uparrow_{-1} &  &  \\
\fbox{${-2}_6$} & \stackrel{-1}{\leftarrow} & \fbox{${-2}_7$} & \stackrel{-1}{\rightarrow} & \fbox{${-2}_7$} \\ 
&  & \downarrow_{-1}  &  &  \\
& & \fbox{${-1.7}_{11}$} &
\end{matrix}
$$
which gives a value
$$
\frac{1}{4}\left( -\frac{7}{4} -1 \right)+
\frac{3}{4}(-2-1)=-\frac{47}{16}
$$
which is equal to -2.9 to 1 d.p (exact value is -2.9375).
The new grid values are
$$
\def\a{-3}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
0 & {-2.4}_1 & {-2.9}_2 & \a_3 \\
\hline
{-2.4}_4 & {-2.9}_5 & \a_6 & {-2.9}_7 \\
\hline
\a_8 & \a_9 & {-2.9}_{10} & {-2.4}_{11} \\
\hline
\a_{12} & {-2.9}_{ 13} & {-2.4}_{14} & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
An optimal policy begins to emerge. For example, at grid point 4 the optimal policy is clearly $\uparrow$. For grid point 5 it is unclear whether we should choose $\leftarrow$ or $\uparrow$ (definitely not $\rightarrow$ or $\downarrow$). For grid point 6, because we use 1 d.p. precision it looks like any decision is optimal. However since grid points 5 and 10 have a value of -2.875 while grid points 2 and 7 have a value of -2.9375 the optimal decision is $\leftarrow$ or $\downarrow$.

Thanks Ted for the breakdown, I’m not confused about how these values go but rather a higher level. Why do the values decrease when the author is saying about monotonically increasing in values $v_{pi}(s)$?

An optimal value function is where $v_{pi’}(s) >= v_{pi}(s)$ for all $s$ right? So why do they become smaller compared to the first $v_{pi}$?

The authors are not saying that $v_k(s)$ should increase with each iteration (in this example it is impossible since any action receives a reward equal to -1). They are saying that a greedy policy will take us from a state with $v_k(s)$ to a state $s'$ with $v_k(s')>v_k(s)$. If you look at the boxes  containing the arrows in your figure they show these eventually converge to the optimal policy. For all iterations the arrows point towards a positive change in value.

I’m not sure if this is true, greedy policy is the argmax of a, not the change from $v(s)$ to $v(s’)$. How would you explain equation 4.8 in the book? How does that fit in with your argument?

The equation is $v_{\pi’}(s) >= v_{\pi}(s)$ for all $s$

Assuming we have the same edition (2nd), read the paragraph after equation (4.6) on p. 78. In particular the sentence "[t]he key criterion is whether this is greater than or less than $v_\pi(s)$."

OK thanks Ted, I think I know where the confusion is from. It's supposed to evaluate $v_{\pi}(s)$ not $v_{\pi'}(s)$ so equation 4.8 doesn't need to hold. I cleared the confusion from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGzpupvSHG8&t=253s
